# core data sync with different data models

Tags: core-data, icloud, core-data-migration

Before I proceed, I'm trying to understand all the issues around core data sync with icloud.  Can anyone tell me or point me to some documentation as to what happens when the data model changes.  For instance I send out a new release of my app which requires a migration to a new data model version.  A user downloads the new release on their iPhone - but not their iPad.  What happens at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncing only happens between devices that have the same model version. If they update the app on one device but not another, syncing will stop until they update their other device. Once they update the other device, syncing is supposed to resume. I'm not completely certain about how reliable this is in practice, but that's what's supposed to happen.

Apple just released a [new guide to using Core Data with iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH1-SW1) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks Tom - this was very helpful.  Sorry I don't have the reputation necessary to up-vote the answer.